# Visible scrollbars in Firefox Mobile on overflown divs

Tags: css, firefox, scrollbar

I have a **`DIV` with a fixed sized** and `overflow:auto` property, to automatically scroll its content if it's taller than available space.

No problem in Desktop environment, default OS' scrollbars will show if necessary, but *this is not true on Smartphones* (I tried with Firefox Mobile).

**Content remains scrollable, but no scrollbar will show**, neither during drag.

Is it a documented feature? I think so, because I noted that Wikipedia's tables in smartphone have the same behaviour when scrolling horizontal.

Is there a way to force it without using a specific JS plugin?

Please, look at [this jsFiddle to try a **working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ldetomi/tefomj80/), both on Desktop and mobile Firefox.

Comment: I think there is an option for webkit using `::-webkit-scrollbar` but isn't no scrollbar expected behaviour on mobile? It would be difficult to use with a touch screen. What I often see is CSS shadows above and below the scroll area to make a visual suggestion of scrollable content.

Comment: Yes, I knew about `::webkit-scrollbar` solution but is not for Firefox, but only fro Chrome (and Safari)